# How can I access the values passed into my app via a custom url scheme from within my C# code?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a **Xamarin Forms** application. It has an `Entry` field for the visit code on the initial page. I need to extend its functionality so that the application will open when a custom url scheme `myscheme://visitcode` is encountered, and the `Entry` will have its `Text` value prepopulated with the value of visitcode.

I've had success with getting the application to launch.

I added my scheme to the `info.plist` file in my iOS project, and it properly launches the app when I click on my custom url scheme in Safari on an iPhone.

I added the following line above my MainActivity in my Droid project:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataScheme = "myscheme")]
```

It properly launches the app when I click on my custom url scheme in Chrome on an Android phone.

The only remaining obstacle is to retrieve the value and populate the `Entry` field with it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I haven't tested this yet, so make sure your app lifecycle and the place where you handle the events are matching the Xamarin.Forms app lifecycle. That is, make sure `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current` is not null. If it is, reshuffle your code to work around that.

For `iOS`, you have to override `OpenUrl` in your `AppDelegate.cs`:

```cs
    public override bool OpenUrl (UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation);
```

and in `Android`, you handle that in your `MainActivity.cs`, in your `OnCreate` or any other method used as entry point:

```cs
var intent = Intent;
var uri = intent.Data;
```

That should allow you to retrieve the parameters of the `url`.

You then can retrieve the current `Xamarin.Forms` `Application` object, by doing:

```cs
var myapp = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as MyApplication;
```

Now, it's up to you to retrieve the right entry, or it's view model, or a service or whatever to connect the dots.

Comment: I was wondering if you could clarify where the Intent instance comes from in MainActivity, OnCreate.  OnCreate takes a Bundle....

Answer (score 0):

There is a component within the Xamarin store that handles this for you:

http://components.xamarin.com/view/rivets

This will remove the lengthy code requirements in building native implementations.

Comment: Link is down. Use NuGet package instead. [Link to project](https://github.com/xamarin/Rivets). The project is not maintained anymore and it has some limitations. E.g. *The Rivets package is not compatible with app-linking in Android 6.0*. So you shouldn't use it anymore.